# Ghost spaces in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

could anybody explain why there're ghost spaces between text and right part of this button in Chrome when used on non one-to-one dpi (looks good in IE) and how to resolve this? The spaces occur at different places depending on the width of the text: sometimes only after the text, sometime before and after the text.

https://jsfiddle.net/y00jm5zk/

```
<span class="button">Button</span>

.button {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(http://www.genesyx.ru/Images/btnleft.png), url(http://www.genesyx.ru/Images/btnright.png), url(http://www.genesyx.ru/Images/btnbg.png);
    background-size: 10px 24px, 11px 24px, 100% 24px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: left, right, left;
    background-origin: border-box, border-box, padding-box;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    border-width: 0 11px 0 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Edited Link for how I see it: http://prntscr.com/buamkx

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, here's the right link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y00jm5zk/

Comment: border-width: 0 11px 0 10px; 
I think this must be the reason for spaces.

Comment: This is required to show round corners on the left and right side of the button. It won't look required way if these are removed.

Comment: For rounded corners use border-radius property.

Comment: This is not really my question. It is more about how to style button with background image, image before text and image after text properly. Here's another example: http://prntscr.com/buavi1

Comment: Why don't you use gradients instead of images?

Comment: Image is more complex than gradients and round corners in the project.